# Python methods (user-defined) returning "builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType'"

Tags: python, class, methods, python-3.x, nonetype

I have this project for college and I'm running into a couple of errors in the test file provided by the teachers.

Most of them are related to this. For example, doing the following:

```
caminho(posicao(0,0)).caminho_junta_posicao('este').caminho_origem()
```

returns:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <fragment>
builtins.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'caminho_origem'
```

However, doing this:

```
c1 = caminho(posicao(0,0))
c1.caminho_junta_posicao('este')
c1.caminho_origem()
```

doesn't return any errors but the intended position.

And I can't figure out why that happens.
Bellow is the code defining both of the classes from the example, as my problem with others lies in very similar. Any help would really be appreciated. Thanks.

```
class posicao:
    def __init__(self,l,c):
        self.posicao=(l,c)
    def posicao_linha(self):
        return self.posicao[0]
    def posicao_coluna(self):
        return self.posicao[1]
    def posicao_igual(self,p2):
        return self.posicao[0] == p2.posicao_linha() and self.posicao[1]\
               == p2.posicao_coluna()
    def posicao_relativa(self,d):
        if d=='norte':
            return posicao(self.posicao_linha()-1,self.posicao_coluna())
        elif d=='sul':
            return posicao(self.posicao_linha()+1,self.posicao_coluna())
        elif d=='este':
            return posicao(self.posicao_linha(),self.posicao_coluna()+1)
        elif d=='oeste':
            return posicao(self.posicao_linha(),self.posicao_coluna()-1)




class caminho:
    def __init__(self,p):
        self.caminho = [p]
    def caminho_junta_posicao(self,d):
        p = self.caminho[-1]
        self.caminho = self.caminho + [p.posicao_relativa(d)]
    def caminho_origem(self):
        return self.caminho[0]
    def caminho_destino(self):
        return self.caminho[-1]
    def caminho_antes_destino(self):
        return self.caminho[:-1]
    def caminho_apos_origem(self):
        return self.caminho[1:]
    def caminho_comprimento(self):
        return len(self.caminho)
    def caminho_contem__ciclos(self):
        for p in range(len(self.caminho)):
            for p2 in self.caminho[p:]:
                if p2.posicao_igual(self.caminho[p]):
                    return True
        return False 
    def caminho_elimina_ciclos(self):
        caminho = self.caminho
        if self.caminho_contem_ciclos():
            for p in caminho:
                for p2 in caminho[caminho.index(p):]:
                    if p.posicoes_iguas(p2):
                        caminho = caminho[:index(p)]+caminho[index(p2):]
```

Comment: Could you post a transcript showing that what you've said happens actually happens? `caminho_junta_posicao` acts in-place and doesn't return anything, so it can't be chained.  As a result, I don't think `c1 = c1.caminho_junta_posicao('este'); c1.caminho_origem()` can have worked, even though you say it did.  Did you mean `c1.caminho_junta_posicao('este'); c1.caminho_origem()` instead?

Comment: Oh, sorry,  that's what I meant. Will edit the question. Does what you said mean I'll have to make it return something?

Comment: Please don't edit the question, or at least don't remove the original examples posted.

Comment: I simply removed something that didn't actually happened. A typo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This method:

```
def caminho_junta_posicao(self,d):
    p = self.caminho[-1]
    self.caminho = self.caminho + [p.posicao_relativa(d)]
```

doesn't explicitly `return` anything, so the result of calling it is `None`.  Therefore,

```
 caminho(posicao(0,0)).caminho_junta_posicao('este')
```

will give `None`, and `None` doesn't have a `caminho_origem()` method, hence your error.

Python convention is usually that methods which act in-place (like `.append`, `.extend`, and here your `.caminho_junta_posicao`) return `None`, which makes chaining like this impossible.  On the other hand, it makes accidentally modifying the original object in a chain which you think is working on copies much harder.  Sometimes chaining does come in handy, though (see the `pandas` library, for example, which makes extensive use of it to great benefit.)

I don't recommend doing this, but if you modified the method to return `self` at the end, i.e.

```
def caminho_junta_posicao(self,d):
    p = self.caminho[-1]
    self.caminho = self.caminho + [p.posicao_relativa(d)]
    return self
```

then the result of `caminho(posicao(0,0)).caminho_junta_posicao('este')` would be your (now-modified) `caminho` object, and you could chain it the way you tried.

Comment: Thanks a lot^^ All answers were helpful but yours was the most detailed. Thanks for the help! Guess I learned something new with this.

Answer (score 0):

The code you expect to work (but doesn't) doesn't work because your method `caminho_junta_posicao()` doesn't explicitly return a value, which means it returns None, causing the error you're seeing.

The code which you stated did work (your second example), didn't actually work when I tried it (Python 3.1.3) -- I got the same error as before.

This is as expected, in that the behavior is consistent.